# HttpWebResponse does not work for first request, works on subsequent requests

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have created a WCF service and hosted it as a Windows Service.
From that WCF service, I am trying to get response from a local server.

But **HttpWebResponse** does not work for first (or sometimes second) request, but works for subsequent requests.

Here is my code:

```
public Hashtable getResponseFromReqtifyServer(String command)
{
    Hashtable httpResponse = new Hashtable();
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    String html = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(command, true)) as HttpWebRequest;                
        request.Method = "GET";                                                 
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.Timeout = 10000000;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                                

        if (response != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
            {
                string name = response.Headers.GetKey(i);
                if (name != "Set-Cookie")
                    continue;
                string[] values = response.Headers.Get(i).Split(';');

                foreach (string value in values)
                {
                    if (value.Contains("ReceiverId"))
                    {                                                                                                        
                        httpResponse.Add("Cookie", value);
                    }
                }
            }

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());                    
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();

            httpResponse.Add("result", html);
            httpResponse.Add("status", "OK");

            reader.Dispose();
            response.Dispose();                                           
        }
        else
        {
            httpResponse.Add("status", "ERROR");
            httpResponse.Add("error", "Response NULL!");
            httpResponse.Add("statusCode", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }                
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        httpResponse.Add("status", "ERROR");
        httpResponse.Add("error", ex.Message);
        if(response == null)
            httpResponse.Add("statusCode", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        else 
            httpResponse.Add("statusCode", response.StatusCode);

        Console.WriteLine(ex);                               
    }               

    return httpResponse;
}
```

For the first time it gives me below error:

> "Unable to connect to remote server"

But for subsequent requests, it does not give me this error.
This error occurs at line :

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

What could be wrong in above code?

EDIT:

Here are some more details for your information.

The type of exception I am getting is `System.Net.WebException`

Details of exception:

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9091
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

Stack Trace:

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Reqtify.ReqtifyServer.getResponseFromReqtifyServer(String command) in F:\Project\ExternalServer\Service\ReqtifyServer.cs:line 59

Comment: I am calling the WCF service method from browser. And in that WCF service method, I am trying to get the response from local server using HttpWebResponse.

Comment: Where do I start a petition so that every time the words `not working` followed by absolutely no description gets me +1 rep? I'd fly past Jon Skeet in about 3 weeks.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you mean by "way of not working". I told you the flow.

Comment: First time it gives me an error : "Unable to connect remote server". But for subsequent requests, it does not give me an error.

Comment: response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); line gives me an error.

Comment: I have updated my original post with this information. Please have a look.

Comment: Any suggestion on this please?